# Sum of Digits using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, sum, sum-of-digits

For our activity today, we were tasked to make using recursion with the sum of digits. I already made this program:

```
int main()

{
int num = 0, sum;

printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

//counter=1;

for ( sum=0; num>0;)

{
    sum = sum + num % 10;
    num = num /10;
  }
printf("Sum = %d", sum);

getch();
return 0;

}
```

Our teacher added "Input and output must be done in the main() function." Am doing the right thing? Or am I missing something in my code?

Comment: This is an iterative (`for` loop) solution and does not use recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do recursion, create a function that recurses rather than using a for loop.

```
int SumDigits(int i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    return i;
  }
  else {
    return i%10 + SumDigits(i/10);
  }
}


scanf("%d", &i);
printf("%d\n", SumDigits(i));
```

Comment: I absolutely hate with a vengeance the `if...return...else` construct :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo  I don't use it much.  It seems easier to understand for new folk.  I prefer the style of your post or the - gasp - `return (i<10) ? foo : bar;`

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an iterative solution, not a recursive one.

Recursion involves defining the problems in terms of a simpler version of the problem, all the time working towards a fixed end point.

The fixed end point in this case is any number less than 10, for which the value is that digit.

The transition to a simpler case (for numbers greater than 9) is simply to add the least significant digit to the result of the number divided by ten (integer division).

Since it's classwork, pseudo-code only I'm afraid.

```
def digitSum (n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return (n % 10) + digitSum (n / 10)
```

If you follow that for the number `314`, you'll see what happens.

- At recursion level one, `n == 314` so it calculates `314 % 10` to get `4` and calls `digitSum(31)`.

  - At recursion level two, `n == 31` so it calculates `31 % 10` to get `1` and calls `digitSum(3)`.

    - At recursion level three, `n == 3` so it just returns `3`
  - Back up to level two, that's added to the remembered `1` and returned as `4`.
- Back up to level one, that's added to the remembered `4` and returned as `8`.

Hence you end up with the digit sum of `8` for the number `314`.